# Action text with email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

How to send mail body in action text?

**Post.rb**

```
has_rich_text :body

after_create :send_email_to_current_user

def send_email_to_current_user
    PostEmailer.create_post(current_user, self)
end
```

**PostEmailer.rb**

```
def create_post(user, post)
   email = user.email
   body = post.body
   mail(to: email, subject: 'create post', body: body)
end
```

I expected body is a string but I got action_text body in an object like

`#<ActionText::RichText id: 12, name: "body", body: #<ActionText::Content "<div class=\"trix-conte...">, record_type: "Post", record_id: 16, created_at: "2020-06-18 11:49:04", updated_at: "2020-06-18 11:49:04">`

**Using rails 6.0, Ruby 2.7.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionText has a few methods to convert from rich text:

Try `.to_s()`

```
mail(to: email, subject: 'create post', body: body.to_s)
```

or `.to_plain_text()`

```
mail(to: email, subject: 'create post', body: body.to_plain_text)
```

or `to_html()`

```
mail(to: email, subject: 'create post', body: body.to_html)
```

Comment: Further reading: [ActionText::Content](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionText/Content.html#method-i-to_plain_text)

Comment: This not showing embedded images.  Could somebody did it?